# Regular Expression or For Loop on String - Split and Join

Tags: javascript, regex, string, for-loop

I am trying to piece together a RegEx that will take a string with this formatting `(person,item(bought,paid),shipping(address(city,state)))` and turn it into a string formatted like this:

```
person
item
* bought
* paid
shipping
* address
** city
** state
```

So far I my lack of understanding RegEx is killing me.  I started doing something like this... but this direction is not going to work:

```
var stg = "(person,item(bought,paid),shipping(address(city,state)))"
var separators = [' ', '\"\\\(', '\\\)\"', ','];
  stg = stg.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'));
```

Note: the string could move around.  I am trying to say if a ( appears start child by adding * if you see ) close child.  I am thinking this might be more on a for loop with a bunch of ifs lol.

Comment: You question is unclear. You want it formatted as a multiline string with `*` characters inserted in them? Or an array of strings?

Comment: @Yathi Preferred multiline string with * added to mark children.  Note the double ** to mark child of the child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own iterator:

```js
str = '(person,item(bought,paid),shipping(address(city,state)))';
counter = -1;
// Split and iterate
str.split(/([(,)])/).filter(Boolean).forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.match(/^[^(,)]/)) {
     console.log("*".repeat(counter) + ((counter > 0) ? ' ' : '') + element)
    } else if (element == '(') {
     counter++;
    } else if (element == ')') {
     counter--;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with one unique replace method:

```js
str='person,item(bought,paid),shipping(address(city,state))';

var asterisks = '';
var result = str.replace(/(\()|(\))|,/g, (match, openP, closingP) => {
    if (openP) {
        return '\n' + (asterisks += '*');
    }
    if (closingP) {
        asterisks = asterisks.slice(1);
        return '';
    }
    // else: is comma
    return '\n' + asterisks;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to have it as a multiline string and not a JSON...
But here you go:

```
var regex = /\((.*?)\,(.*?)\((.*?),(.*?)\),(.*?)\((.*?)\((.*?),(.*?)\)\)\)/;
var string = '(person,item(bought,paid),shipping(address(city,state)))';

var matches = string.match(regex)

var resultString = matches[1] + "\n";
resultString += matches[2] + "\n" ;
resultString += "* " + matches[3] + "\n" ;
resultString += "* " + matches[4] + "\n" ;
resultString += matches[5] + "\n" ;
resultString += "* " + matches[6] + "\n" ;
resultString += "** " + matches[7] + "\n" ;
resultString += "** " + matches[8];

console.log(resultString);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without relying on matches?  As in if the string was move about.  So more of noticing that ( begins a child and ) closes?